# request.client.host is working in one server but not in other server?

Tags: nginx, ip, client, gunicorn, fastapi

We are using same gunicorn and nginx configuration in both servers. one server it is giving client ip but not in other server. Both are ubuntu servers.

we are developing rest API services by using fastAPI framework. we are running gunicorn behind the nginx.
below are the gunicorn.py file

```
import os

errorlog = '/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
bind = 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock'
daemon = True
workers = os.cpu_count() * 2
timeout = 600
graceful_timeout = 600
keepalive = 60
worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
max_requests = 2048
preload_app = True
max_requests_jitter = 1024
worker_connections = 1000
proxy_protocol = True
forwarded_allow_ips = "*"
proxy_allow_ips = "*"
```

we are running above gunicorn.py file using **gunicorn -c gunicorn.py base.main:app**
we are getting client ip by using **request.client.host**

Comment: Issue got resolved by recreating my virtual environment again. Removed existing environment and created again in the serve. it's working now.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved by recreating my virtual environment again. Removed existing environment and created again in the serve. it's working now.